# How to get backward and forward word keyboard shortcuts working in a Mac OSX Terminal

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

I miss being able to use Alt-B and Alt-F for backward and forward word in a Mac Terminal window (and any editor really).

Is there a way to enable them; currently they print the symbols ∫ƒ instead, which are not that useful to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of OS X and what application? If Terminal.app, try Preferences -> Settings -> Keyboard. Make sure that *Use option as meta key* is checked. With that, in 10.6.5, ⌥F and ⌥B work as expected in Terminal.app, but print ƒ and ∫ in iTerm and elsewhere, as you have observed. Note that in other applications, ⌥→ and ⌥← can be used to jump words.

Comment: Apple's  list of  keys is http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343 which seems to be incomplete as it does not include ⌥→ and ⌥← but they do work

Comment: "Use option as meta key" fixes it thanks. I'm using 10.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Try Control-F and Control-B.  You can also use Control-A to jump to the start of the line and control-E to jump to the end

Comment: What applications do ⌃F and ⌃B work in?

Comment: ^B and ^f just move forward one character

Comment: Yes, that appears to be what justin was asking. ^f and ^b work in Terminal and Text edit at least. If he actually meant "backward and forward [a] word" then that wasn't what he needed. Sorry. Was it really as bad as -1?